# external javascript loaded by javascript sometimes not working in IE

Tags: javascript

I made this function to load inline javascript, html and external javascript from an array and it seems to work in all browsers but occasionally in ie9 and ie10 it loads the internal js and html but not the external files.

http://jsfiddle.net/fjfzmf2d/10/

```
// Append js and html.
function _append(selector, arr) {
    var content = arr;
    for(var i = 0; i< content.length; i++) {
        var _content = content[i];
        var js = _content.indexOf('script');
        if(js > -1) {
            // Script tag.
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            var regex = /<script.*?src="(.*?)"/gmi;
            var url = regex.exec(_content);
            var inline = '';
            if(url) {
                script.src = url[1];
            }
            _content.replace(/<script[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/script>/gi, function(){
                inline += arguments[1] + '\n';
            });
            script.text = inline;
            selector.appendChild(script);
        } else {
            // html content.
            selector.innerHTML += _content;
        }
    }
}
// Selector - div or tag.
var selector = document.body;

// Array with inline and external javascript.
var arr = [];
// Inline javascript.
arr.push('<script>alert("inline javascript");</\script>');
arr.push('<script>alert("more inline javascript");</\script>');
// External script.
arr.push('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://chrismills.la/test.js"></\script>');
// html.
arr.push('<p>Content.</p>');
arr.push('<p>More Content.</p><p>More Content 2.</p>');

_append(selector, arr);
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with all the regular expressions?

Comment: one gets the url from an external script string in the array and one creates inline javascript from code between the <script> tags for inline javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work even in IE8.  Basically create a script element for inline script and eval() the .text of that script.  Then use document.write to append external scripts but escape the </script>.  The functions could use some cleanup but hopefully someone finds this useful.

```
// Append js.
function _appendJS(jsobj, d, selector) {
    var _content = d;
    var _selector = selector;
    var _jsobj = jsobj;
    // Create script tag for inline js.
    if(_jsobj.inline) {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.text = _jsobj.inline;
      document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(script);
    }
    // Write urls for external js.
    if(_jsobj.urls) {
        for(var i=0; i<_jsobj.urls.length; i++) {
            var _url = _jsobj.urls[i];
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.src = _url;
            document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(script);
        }
    }
    // Append html content.
    _appendHTML(_content, _selector);
}

// Append html.
function _appendHTML(d, selector) {
    if(selector) {
        selector.innerHTML += d;
    } else {
        console.log('Invalid selector provided.');
    }
}

// Append.
function _append(d, selector) {
    var content = d;
    var js = content.match(/<script/g);
    // Javascript and html.
    if(js) {
        var urls = [];
        var inline = '';
        var regInline = /<script[^type="(.*?)">]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/script>/gmi;
        var regSrc = /<script.*?src="(.*?)"><\/script>/gmi;
        // Extract inline javascript.
        content = content.replace(regInline, function(){
            inline += arguments[1] + '\n';
            return '';
        });
        // Extract external javascript urls.
        content = content.replace(regSrc, function(){
            urls.push(arguments[1]);
            return '';
        });
        var jsobj = {
            'inline': inline,
            'urls': urls
        }
        _appendJS(jsobj, content, selector)
    // Html.
    } else {
        _appendHTML(content, selector);
    }
}

var selector = document.getElementById('content');

var d = '<script>alert("inline javascript 1");</\script><h1>html only</h1><h2>subtitle.</h2><script>alert("inline javascript 2");</\script><script>alert("inline javascript 3");</\script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://chrismills.la/test.js"></\script><script>alert("more inline javascript");</\script><p>More Content.</p>';

_append(d, selector);
```